Plot the graph of the function f(x)=\sqrt(1-x^2)
Why is the graph I drew discontinuous at the point x=1?
Is there a way to still use f(x) without it being discontinuous?
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, font=\footnotesize, line join=round, line cap=round, >=stealth, declare function={f(\x)=sqrt(1-(\x)^2);}]
    \draw[smooth, samples=1000, domain=-1:1] plot (\x, {f(\x)});
    \draw (-1,0)--(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}



Welcome to TeX:SE! Please insert copy of your code from your editor and paste in your question. It then we can copy to our editors and test it. Image of code doesn't allow this ... Be aware, tat your function at end of domains id perpendicular and therefore require special care about number of samples there.

Please, edit question and move above code there.

The issue is the precision of PGF's floating point operations. You don't really get the point 1.0 from your domain. The last calculated point is 0.9989 (the first is indeed -1.0).

Is there any solution to this?

Welcome // Looks like a line join problem to me. See: https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#pgf./tikz/line:join . // Please: Next time post code, which compiles. Fragments most of the time leave too many questions unanswered. Thank you

@Skillmon, sorry to ping you but  I was just interested if the precision of PGF's floating point operations could be overcome somehow? I've looked online and found the fpu library, but it doesn't seem to be for tikzpictures. Does lualatex do this? Pardon me for my lack of understanding.

@Jasper PGF's precision is basically the same as TeX's as it uses dimensions for its calculations. And yes, you have to be careful when to activate the fpu, if you do this while drawing the coordinate calculations break and TikZ/TeX complains that Y is not a valid unit. I think the easiest fix was if TikZ made sure that the two end points of a range are always used (and if the steps inbetween aren't equidistant that's not that bad).

@Jasper for instance you can locally turn on the FPU in a function, but need to end the scope and smuggle the result in a normal float format.

Sure there is a simple solution to the problem, just add the last point manually. What plot does is simply evaluating your function and put them on a list of coordinates connected by -- (well in principle, the actual code might look a bit different), you can simply add another point after it.
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, font=\footnotesize, line join=round, line cap=round, >=stealth, declare function={f(\x)=sqrt(1-(\x)^2);}]
    \draw[smooth, samples=1000, domain=-1:1] plot (\x, {f(\x)}) -- (1, 0);
    \draw (-1,0)--(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You can even put everything inside the same \draw statement and use cycle to get a single path from your input:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, font=\footnotesize, line join=round, line cap=round, >=stealth, declare function={f(\x)=sqrt(1-(\x)^2);}]
    \draw plot[smooth, samples=1000, domain=-1:1] (\x, {f(\x)})
      -- (1, 0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Result looks roughly the same (might be a bit better at the edges where the two lines merge).

Good solution (+1)! However, the following simplify code also works: \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=sqrt(1-(\x)^2);}] \draw plot[samples=200, domain=-1:1] (\x, {f(\x)}) -- (1, 0) -- cycle; \end{tikzpicture}

@Zarko that's already in my answer (there are two code blocks, the second is identical to your comment's code, except for the extra options set by OP which I left untouched).

And yes, the sample size 1000 is vastly too many points :) 200 should suffice.

You can add the following code to your preamble
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@plot@samples@recalc#1:#2\relax{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}%
  \let\tikz@temp@start=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \let\tikz@temp@end=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{\tikz@temp@start + (\tikz@temp@end - \tikz@temp@start) / (\tikz@plot@samples - 1)}
  \edef\tikz@plot@samplesat{\tikz@temp@start, \pgfmathresult, ..., \tikz@temp@end, \tikz@temp@end}
}
\makeatother

\documentclass[border = .5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@plot@samples@recalc#1:#2\relax{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}%
  \let\tikz@temp@start=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \let\tikz@temp@end=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathparse{\tikz@temp@start + (\tikz@temp@end - \tikz@temp@start) / (\tikz@plot@samples - 1)}
  \edef\tikz@plot@samplesat{\tikz@temp@start, \pgfmathresult, ..., \tikz@temp@end, \tikz@temp@end}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, font=\footnotesize, line join=round, line cap=round, >=stealth, declare function={f(\x)=sqrt(1-(\x)^2);}]
  \draw[smooth, samples=1000, domain=-1:1] plot (\x, {f(\x)});
  \draw (-1,0)--(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



If you're goal is just to draw a semicircle you can use the arc path to achieve much better results in a much easier way:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1, 0) arc[start angle = 180, end angle=0, radius=1] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


